# Neo4j cyper query: How to travese

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to learn neo4j, so I just took a use case of a travel app to learn but I am not sure about the optimal way to solve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

So consider a use case in which I have to travel from one place (**PLACE A**) to other (**PLACE C**) by train, but there is no direct connection between the two places. And so we have to change our train in **PLACE B**.

Two places are connected via a relation **IS_CONNECTED** relation. *refering to green nodes in the image*

And then if there is an is_connected relation between two place then there will be an out going relation i.e. **CONNECTED_VIA** to a common train from both the node which implies how they are connected *referring to red nodes in image*

my question is how are we suppose to know that we have to change the station from place b

My understanding is:

1. We will check where the two places are connected via IS_CONNECTED relationship

   match (start:place{name:"heidelberg"}), (end:place{name:"frankfurt"})
   MATCH path = (start)-[:IS_CONNECTED*..]->(end)
   RETURN path

this will show that these two places are connected

2. Then we will see that if place A and place c are directly connected or not by the query

   match (p:place{name:"heidelberg"})-[:CONNECTED_VIA]->(q)<-[:CONNECTED_VIA]-(t:place{name:"frankfurt"})
   return q

And this will return nothing because there is no direct connections

3. My brain stopped functioning after this. I am trying to figure how from past 3 days. I am sorry I look ao confused

[Please click here for the image of what i am referring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxdfM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use variable-length relationships in your :CONNECTED_VIA match, and then get the :Place nodes that are in your path. And it's usually a good idea to use an upper bound, whatever makes sense in your graph.

Then we can use a filter on the nodes in your path to only keep the ones that are :Place nodes.

```
match path = (p:place{name:"heidelberg"})-[:CONNECTED_VIA*..4]-(t:place{name:"frankfurt"}) 
return path, [node in nodes(path)[1..-1] where node:Place] as connectionPlaces
```

And if you're only interested in the shortest paths, you may want to check the [shortestPath() or shortestPaths() functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path).

One last thing to note...when determining if two locations are connected, if all you need is a true or false if they're connected, you can use the EXISTS() function to return whether such a pattern exists:

```
match (start:place{name:"heidelberg"}), (end:place{name:"frankfurt"}) 
return exists((start)-[:IS_CONNECTED*..5]->(end))
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! this is what I was looking for